# crmsvcutil.exe: Unable to generate entity classes for early binding - Dynamics CRM Online

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I am trying to generate early bound entity classes from my Dynamics CRM Online instance.

I have CRM SDK installed on my machine.

I am running following command from the "Bin" folder of SDK.

```
crmsvcutil.exe /url:<<OrganizationServiceUrl>> /out:crmexams3.cs /username:"<<username>>" /password:"<<password>>"
```

But this gives me following error:

```
Error requesting orgs from the discovery server
Access is denied
```

I have replaced the OrganizationServiceUrl with the organization service url which I could found from Developer resources in CRM instance.

My instance is CRM 2016 Online.

Any idea why this is failing?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you put `/il` as an argument and remove the username and password you can enter the credentials, domain, etc through a XRMTooling Login Control. Entering it in manually has the benefits of:

- It will potentially fix your problem.
- It makes it so you aren't storing credentials somewhere, which is a little bit of a security faux paux.

Answer (score 0):

`Access is denied` suggests you have the wrong user name and password provided.

There are examples of how the command line should look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx#bkmk_examples), perhaps your username is in the wrong format?

> The first example is for the Microsoft account identity provider and
>   the second is for the Office 365 identity provider.

```
CrmSvcUtil.exe /url:https://myorg.api.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc    /out:GeneratedCode.cs /username:"myname@live.com" /password:"myp@ssword!" 

CrmSvcUtil.exe /url:https://myorg.api.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc    /out:GeneratedCode.cs /username:"myname@myorg.onmicrosoft.com" /password:"myp@ssword!"
```

Comment: the possibility of incorrect user name and password is not there, as I use the same credentials to connect to crm instance which works fine there. I am using the same command and syntax as you have provided in the example. This seems to be some odd issue. I found more convenient mechanism that is to use "Early bound generator" plugin provided in Xrm Toolbox which does this job efficiently.